# String.Replace with \ in it?

Tags: c#

How can I replace the "\" in a string with a double slash "\\"?

I tried String.Replace("\","\\") but then intellisense stops working :(

Thanks!

Comment: I love the meta-joke here... SO itself replaces double-backslash with a single one, so the question seemed stupid before the edit :)

Comment: Hehe yeah. I fixed the first instance after reading the solution, but I think I forgot to do the second one. Testament to these guys skill, they knew what was going on even though the question didn't appear right!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
String.Replace("\\","\\\\")
```

This is because a character can follow \, which makes a special character. \" means put a literal double quote in the string, rather than close it.

Here are some common ones:
`\n` - Line feed
`\r` - Carriage return (Windows newlines are `\r\n`)
`\t` - Tab

The other answers, which say to use `@"\"` are right and easier to understand, so should probably be used instead.

Comment: Thank you much, I appreciate the full explanation and also directing me towards the @ method for brevity.

Answer (score 11):

`\` is a reserved character in a string, it's an "escape". So, for instance, `\n` means a linefeed constant.

`string.Replace(@"\", @"\\")` would work just fine -- the `@` tells the compiler to ignore the escaping of `\`.

Alternatively, `\\` means one backslash -- so `string.Replace("\\", "\\\\")` would work just fine too (although it's a bit unreadable).

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the short example as well as the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use '@' to make backslash lose its special meaning:

```
String.Replace(@"\", @"\\")
```